# All bean attributes are assigned null

Tags: spring-boot, jsf, primefaces

I'm writing an application using Spring Boot. I'd like to create an instance of the bean LobbyBean, but after heaving filled out the form, all attributes are still null. Does anybody have an idea, why the input data doesn't get through to the controller? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the (simplified) code:

LobbyBean

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class LobbyBean {

@GeneratedValue
private int pin;
private QuestionSet questionSet;
private User host;
private QuestionDifficulty questionDifficulty;
private int maxNumberOfPlayers;
private boolean hasJoker;

// getters and setters for all attributes
```

LobbyController

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class LobbyController {

@Autowired
private GameManager gameManager;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

private LobbyBean newLobby = new LobbyBean();

// getter and setter for newLobby

public void createLobby()
{
   newLobby.setHost(userService.getAuthenticatedUser());
   gameManager.saveLobby();
   newLobby = new LobbyBean();
}
```

lobbycreation.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="content">

    <h:form id="lobbysettings">
        <p:panel>
        <h:panelGrid id="settings" columns="2">

            <p:outputLabel value="Questionset: "/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="questionset" value="#{lobbyController.newLobby.questionSet}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{lobbyDetailController.allQuestionSetNames}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Difficulty: "/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="difficulty" value="#{lobbyController.newLobby.questionDifficulty}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{lobbyDetailController.allQuestionDifficulties}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Max Num of Players: "/>
            <p:inputNumber decimalPlaces="0" value="#{lobbyController.newLobby.maxNumberOfPlayers}" />

            <p:outputLabel value="Joker?"/>
            <p:inputSwitch value="#{lobbyController.newLobby.hasJoker}" />

            <p:commandButton id="createLobbyButton" value="Lobby Erstellen" process="@this"
                             action="#{lobbyController.createLobby}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

Comment: Does it work if you do not use a template? (see http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info the [mcve] part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `process="@this"`on your p:commandButton with `process="@form"` otherwise only the commandButton will be part of the submit.

Comment: #9 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value...